# Execute two Jobs paralley in same thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt4, qthread

I have a QThread  for connecting to SSH server

Say two jobs Job 1 and Job 2 want to execute few commands in server. In my current code if Job 1 start executes and in the middle if Job 2 comes then job 2 commands executes and Job 1 command stops

JOb 1

```
mkdir
ls
qstat
```

While doing ls of Job 1 if job 2 access the same thread  and executes mkdir then Job 2 mkdir executes and qstat of Job 1 will not execute later

How to solved this.

I want both Job 1 and Job 2 should execute parallely without creating any issue. Is there any possiblility to split the thread T1 into two different thread.

In real case more jobs may execute commands in server

Comment: This is not clear. Are the 2 jobs using the same SSH connection? To the same server? There are a lot of way to make "jobs" run in parallel here, you have threads and ssh connection on your local PC and ssh session and processes on the remote server.

Comment: Yes currently all jobs using the same SSH connection to same server. SSH code I kept in Thread all JObs access this thread to send data to same server.
I want all jobs should execute parallely without interrupting the there activity one another

I was thinking to create multiple thread for each Job but it is hetic and my job count increases in run time

Comment: Multiple thread not looks good because I need to bind to different address each time and its taking few second to establish connection. IF same thread can do parallel submission then it will be very nice

Comment: Your first issue is not in the Qt app, but on your server. If you run `cmd1` in job 1 and `cmd2` in job 2, `cmd2` will not run until `cmd1` is finished. You can do `cmd1 &` to force the process in the background, but you will get mixed output from `cmd1` and `cmd2`. And even if you solve that, you mays have some conflicts between 2 jobs what if the job 1 does `cd path` and `rm -rf *` and job 2 does `cd /` and `ls`, if you mix them you might end up calling `rm -rf *` in `/`.

Comment: Jb 1 and Jb 2 activities are different and not working on same common resource in server. The problem is both Job using same channel to connect to server so if Jb2 sends some message to server while jb 1 is using then before completing JB1 message Jb 2 activity is executing.

Comment: I want both Jb1 and Jb2 activity to execute parallely using the same channel or some alternative